# Would it be against the JLS's philosophy to compress do...while like this?

Tags: java, optimization, do-while, jls

While writing another `do ... while` loop in Java, I started thinking about its syntax. A typical programmer will write something like

```
do {
  somethng();
}while(booleanValue);
```

However, Java has a built-in way of compressing this by allowing the programmer to remove the braces when only one line is inside the loop (this is typical for Java expressions):

```
do
  something();
while(booleanValue);
```

This can be thought of and written as

```
do something();
while(booleanValue);
```

or even as

```
do;
while(booleanValue);
```

This is quite interesting. This brought my attention to the fact that this is a Java statement that must be read and run spanning two lines, meaning that after the `do` line is run, then the operation is not complete until the `while` line is run. Remember that other expressions are only one line:

```
if(booleanValue) something();
while(booleanValue) something();
for(Object declaration; booleanValue; operation()) something();
for(Object declaration : iterableObject) something();
throw throwableObject;
return anyObject;
switch(integer) {}
//case is excluded because it operates a lot more like a goto operation than a statement
```

So I started thinking, not about why this is, but about how to compress this statement a bit more.

Assuming that a "line" is anything that's terminated in a semicolon (`;`) or contained within braces (`{` and `}`), let's go into this with this knowledge: **a `do` statement necessarily requires two lines to be run** and **a `do` statement is must continue running *at least* until it reaches an empty `while` statement**.

**So why ever use braces?**

Let's look at some scenarios with this syntax. How about a `do...while` statement with one enclosed statement:

```
do something();
while(booleanValue();
```

Alright, nothing new, here. What about `do...while` statement with three enclosed statements:

```
do
  statement1();
  statement2();
  statement3();
while(booleanValue);
```

Here, Java will see that it is a `do` statement, and it will run lines 2, 3, and 4 before seeing the empty `while` statement. At this point, it knows we're ready to end the loop, evaluate the expression, and possibly return to the `do` or exit the loop.

How about something that you might think breaks it; a nested `while` loop:

```
do
  statement1();
  while(booleanValue1)
    statement2();
while(booleanValue2);
```

Here, Java sees it's a `do` statement and enters it, then runs line 2 normally. At line `3`, it sees that it's a `while` statement. At this point it must decide whether this is the end of the loop. It inspects the `while` statement and discovers that it is not empty, and therefore not the end of the `do` loop. It enters the `while` statement and loops lines 3 and 4 until it doesn't anymore. It then sees another `while` statement and, upon inspection, sees that it is empty and, therefore, the end of the `do` statement. It evaluates it and may or may not return to line 2, but we don't care right now.

> But Supuhstar, that sure seems like a lot of calculation! Won't that slow down the JVM?

Not necessarily! This can all be done at compile time, much like Java determines if any other statement listed above is empty (for instance, trying to compile `while(true);` will result in the next line compiling with the error "`unreachable statement`").

So, much like

```
for(Object declaration : iterableObject)
  somethingInvolving(declaration);
```

compiles into

```
Iterator<Object> i = iterableObject.iterator();
while(i.hasNext())
{
  Object declaration = i.next();
  somethingInvolving(declaration);
}
```

then

```
do
  statement1();
  while(booleanValue1)
    statement2();
while(booleanValue2);
```

could compile into

```
do
{
  statement1();
  while(booleanValue1)
  {
    statement2();
  }
}
while(booleanValue2);
```

> But Supuhstar, Java doesn't care about indentation! Can yours be written with any indentation, or none at all?

Certainly! The compiler would just as easily compile

```
do
  statement1();
  while(booleanValue1)
    statement2();
while(booleanValue2);
```

as it would

```
do statement1(); while(booleanValue1) statement2(); while(booleanValue2);
```

and both of these would do exactly the same thing.

**Does anyone else agree that this would be an okay thing to include as Java syntax, or is there some glaring reason I'm missing that this cannot be done?**

Comment: `;` is an empty statement in Java, and that's why `do; while(true);` compiles fine!

Comment: I'm sure a parser can handle that, but how about the next programmer's eyes? In other words it is probably ok but why would you want to do that?

Comment: I hate braces; python does the right thing

Comment: I know this, @Eng.Fouad. That is also why `do{}while(true);` compiles fine. However, like I said for the third code snippet, it can be thought of as having `do` and `while` be two separate statements.

Comment: @assylias see the tags; it's for code compression/optimization. Same reason anypony uses JQuery. Heck, same reason we use these compiled languages instead of Basic, Assembler, or ML.

Comment: @Supuhstar the problem is that contrary to some other languages (python for example), indentation has no particular meaning in Java as you know. Until it does (if ever) what you propose seems difficult to justify...

Comment: @assylias I'm sorry you think this is indentation-dependent. That second-to-last snippet can just as easily be written `do statement1(); while(booleanValue1) statement2(); while(booleanValue2);`. Again, sorry for confusing you.

Comment: @assylias I hope my most recent edit helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This particular statement struck my as slightly confused:

> It inspects the while statement and discovers that it is not empty,
>   and therefore not the end of the do loop.

Because what do you mean by "not empty"? while-loops are allowed to be "empty":

```
do
  statement1();
while(booleanValue1);
while(booleanValue2);
```

That would be valid under your plan even though the first while-loop would close the do-while instead of the second.

That being said, the grammar you are suggesting would not be [ambiguous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambiguous_grammar) I don't think .... but doesn't matter because it would never be introduced because the language designers are not (and never have been) interested in making Java a cleaner or more terse language.

You could even say verbosity is fundamental part of the Java philosophy. There **many** things the compiler could infer or allow but doesn't. The good news is there are many more modern languages like Scala that allow you to write more brief, expressive code.

Comment: Yes, your code snippit would be valid and compilable, but it would be a programmer error. This simply means that they were taught wrong, much like the hanging else.

Comment: On your mention about not making Java cleaner... what about the `for`-each loop I showed above? Doesn't that count?

Comment: @Supuhstar -- Yes the `for-each` counts and there have also been a few other examples over the past decade or so.

Comment: Then why did you say "and never have been"?

Answer (score 3):

Think about this code

```
    if(true)
        if(false)
            System.out.println("x");
    else
        System.out.println("y");
```

it prints "y". Sometimes, it's too confusing to humans without braces.

Comment: +1 Braces are amazing. Though occasionally humanity is benefited by leaving them out... just once or twice.

Comment: which nobody should have had to know.

Comment: "It's too confusing" is subjective. I can understand it just fine. Fine enough to understand that you didn't indent that properly, unless your point was that it's confusing.

Comment: or - I indented properly, but didn't brace it properly.

Comment: @irreputable +1 I've had to work on code like that, where it's almost impossible to tell if the indenting got "corrupted" by differing tab lengths, or if someone just screwed up the code.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to what irreputable said, I've also seen this example:

```
if(false)
    //System.out.println("x");

System.out.println("Done");
```

Can you see why the second print doesn't get run?